# Having display device issues on Ubuntu 18.04 after updating NVIDIA graphics drivers?

Tags: command-line, drivers, nvidia, display-resolution, ubuntu-drivers

I updated my graphics drivers, and now in the display settings, it says 'Unknown Device' instead of the displays I have. (I have two.) The second display doesn't work, and indeed doesn't appear in the settings, and on the first, I can't change the screen resolution - which is inconvenient, since that's been shrunken.

Is there anything I can do? I've tried ubuntu-driver devices and the autoinstall command thereof, and I've tried deleting the config file for displays. Neither of them worked.

If any further info is required, I'll do my best to deliver, but I'll be the first to admit that I'm not the best with this sort of thing.